# Laptop freezing randomly — HDD light turns off

Tags: hard-drive, laptop-repair, check-disk

I have a GP62X Leopard Pro laptop from MSI. 
I had it for about two months and then it randomly started to have moments where it would freeze for a few seconds or would look as if it was running at 3 fps.

After researching, I assumed it was the HDD (1 TB HDD). So I decided to run a full chkdsk scan and during the process "Scanning and Repairing Drive  (C:) 11% Complete" it freezes. And no, I don't mean that it is just stuck  on 11% and I have to let it sit for a few hours for it to progress. I mean the spinning dots that indicate loading or progress is currently being made, are no longer spinning. They are frozen and the HDD light is off. I can send the laptop in; hopefully the warranty covers this, which it should, but I have to wait until my classes finish. So I'm just looking for a solution now that could hopefully work.

Things I've tried:

- Normal `chkdsk` with no options, just my main drive as a parameter.
- Running scans to check for S.M.A.R.T. Errors. I believe I've tried CrystalDiskInfo, which said my drive was in good standing.
- I ran the error checking tool provided by Windows through the tools GUI in the properties of my C: drive.
- Looking for certain drivers for my disk drive, however, the site for the brand of HDD I have doesn't have the drivers or even the type of hard-drive on their site anymore I don't think. So rolling back or updating isn't possible as far as I know.

Any help on this? I could maybe purchase a 128 GB SSD and place it into my laptop myself (as it is optional) and run my OS off of that instead. however, I do not want to run the risk of voiding my warranty.

UPDATE:
After traversing through Windows 10's Advanced Startup options, I booted in safemode with the command line and performed a `chkdsk c: /f` again. It appears my hard disk is still going. The light is on and I can hear it whirring away faintly. The spinning dots that indicate loading and such are gone, but this must be the part of the process that people get stuck up on and believe it hangs. I shall keep it going as long as I can tell the hard disk is moving. Will update on any progress made. Hopefully this fixes my original issue.

UPDATE 2:
After about 2 or 3 hours stuck on 11%, my laptop restarted and went into diagnosing. It said the pc couldn't start properly and took me back to the advanced options menu. I then just clicked restart pc and it scanned again but said it was at 100%. My laptop then booted up as it normally would. No clue if it fixed anything. Event viewer had nothing relating to `chkdsk` in it so I'm not sure.

Comment: @G-Man thanks for the edit. I'm on mobile (browser) so I couldn't really utilize markup or anything.

Comment: You’re welcome.   As long as I have your attention: your last (fourth) bullet seems to be missing something.

Comment: Oh right. Edited :)

Comment: Try running checkdisk after rebooting in safe mode or from a live CD as described in method 3 & 4 here: http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Chkdsk-Function